# VS Code terminating a task with Ctrl - Alt - M will not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a piece of code running on my computer, but in order to terminate it, I would supposedly have to press ctrl-alt-m, but doing that does nothing as my code runs forever. Instead, I have to press f1 and terminate it that way. Is there any way that this could be fixed because the shortcut is less of a hassle.

Comment: who is handling the Ctrl-Alt-M? VSC or the C++ program. What do you get with F1? (usually help)

Comment: Every Intro student needs to learn about Ctrl+c to BREAK out of your program.